# Why has Koh been estranged from the Mother of Faces?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Spoilers for The Last Airbender comics (The Search, Part 3).

We're shown the the Mother of Faces is the mother of Koh, the face stealer. She tells us that he's been estranged from her since time began:

[image]

What exactly separated them? We see that the Mother of Faces can traverse from the Spirit World to the Material World just fine, so I doubt it is because both worlds are divided.

Answer (score 2):

This estrangement hasn't been directly discussed in the show or comics (yet?).  But we can look at many mythologies to see parallels that they many have been drawing on.  From the Greek Myths where child gods often are turned against their parents by their very natures.  Also in Taoist stories there are many parents that produce offspring that are their polar opposites.